# Where are OS-level crash reports stored?

Tags: crash, logs

I have a machine that has some intermittent rebooting. When it restarts, I get the familiar dialog to report this to Apple. I don't always remember to save the details of the crash. I'm sure that those logs are stored in the FS somewhere. Does anyone know where?

To be 100% clear, I'm not talking about application crashes, which are easily viewable in Console, I mean OS-level panics.

Comment: I don't have a crash report to cross check things, but check `/Library/Logs` and `/var/logs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They live in `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`.